# Summary has been specified on a non-recurring field

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I get an error when I try to use the formulas below. Where have I gone wrong, and how can I resolve this?

Formula 1: "IncomeTax3"

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
global numbervar sumvalue;

sumvalue:= Sum ({Sp_Rpt_PayrollViewMonthly;1.InTax},
{Sp_Rpt_PayrollViewMonthly;1.sReference})
```

Formula 2: "Total Deduction"

```
({Sp_Rpt_PayrollViewMonthly;1.AdvAdj} + 
{Sp_Rpt_PayrollViewMonthly;1.BikeDed} + {Sp_Rpt_PayrollViewMonthly;1.GPDedMan} 
+ {Sp_Rpt_PayrollViewMonthly;1.GPDedNon} + {@InTax3} )
```

This is the error I get:

> A summary has been specified on a non-recurring field

Comment: In which formula are you getting this error?

Comment: a summary has been specified on a non-recurring field Details: @TotalDeduction

Comment: i got error in my 2nd Formula. incometax formula give the right result in report but when in put (+ @IncomeTax3) in my 2nd formula it gives an error.   ({Sp_Rpt_PayrollViewMonthly;1.AdvAdj} + 
{Sp_Rpt_PayrollViewMonthly;1.BikeDed} + {Sp_Rpt_PayrollViewMonthly;1.GPDedMan} 

+ {Sp_Rpt_PayrollViewMonthly;1.GPDedNon} + {@IncomeTax3} )

Comment: Moreover I applied my first formula Incometax3 on a group footer section. i applied group section in employee reference field in payrollviewmontlhy table in my report.

Comment: you cant use WhilePrintingRecords in a summary formula :)

Comment: In second foemula few fields are from database and one is summation more over income tax is in footer..in which section have you placed second formula

Comment: Dear siva, thanks for the reply income tax is in the group section footer of the report while in the same section i use my second formula..

Comment: i re-run report without whileprintingrecords no such results same error exists.

Comment: The error doesn't follow until much later, so edited to clarify slightly.